# Can I specify different mysql connection for a model method in laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I know we can specify a mysql connection for a particular model by setting

`protected $connection = 'my_db';`

But is there a way to specify a different connection than what the model is using for a specific method.

For example if my model is using `my_db` as default connection, but I want model method `foo()` to use a different connection `my_db1`. How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eloquent uses Query Builder under the hood, so you can try to use `connection()` in model method:

```
return $this->connection('foo')->where('id', 1)->get();
```

Comment: my connection name is `my_db1` which I defined in `.env` file. my model method is like `public function foo() {}`. I want `foo()` to access diff connection.

Comment: You need to define all connections you're using in the app in `/config/database.php` config file. Then just use `connection()` when you're building the query. If your query is in model, just use the code from my answer and change `foo` to connection name which you're defined in config file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DB::connection($connName)`.

Look in the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/database

Comment: where do I set it?